# Gradle sync failed: org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V (1 s 810 ms)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Gradle sync failed: Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824.
            Searched in the following locations:
            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.pom
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar
            Required by:
            project :ViewPagerIndicator-Library > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.5.2 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.5.2 (20 s 410 ms)

16:00   NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=4.6, NDK version is UNKNOWN

16:07   Gradle sync started with single-variant sync

16:07   Gradle sync failed: org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V (1 s 810 ms)

16:07   NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

Comment: Can you post your gradle.build?

Comment: its already mention in error that you have error in `ViewPagerIndicator-Library` that you have in gradle file.

Comment: but what is the issue with viewPagerIndicator-Library. I am not able to understand. if anybody would answer for this then its really helpful